# In a copy operation why does macOS Big Sur send a lot of packets to the hard drive it is copying from?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, file-transfer

Copying a large file from an external hard drive to a Mac, shows a lot of packets first going to the hard drive.

[image]

Then there is a period of no disk activity.

[image]

Then what I expected happens, packets arrive to the Mac from the hard drive.

[image]

What is the Mac sending to the hard drive before the copy operation?

Comment: Presumably this is a network drive? What type of network & connection?

Comment: This is amazing question. Can I ask you to edit in the version of macos? I’ll try to answer with a tool that works to pick apart what is happening. Is this Big Sur?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a network drive, then the packets are likely it reading the contents of the folder.

If it's not a network drive, then the packets are unrelated to your external disk.

Comment: How is 'reading the contents of the folder' showing up as a huge transmission of packets FROM the mac TO the external hard drive.?

Comment: Remember that packets don't reflect the amount of data being sent. You should switch it to data to see that amount of data. Presumably, depending on the protocol, listing the contents of a directory would be 1 or more packets. Then perhaps listing file information for a specific file could be another set of packets.